# Using active record callbacks to update model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Suppose I have a Rails app that deals with `Posts` and `Comments`. A Post `has_many` Comments and each Comment `belongs_to` a Post.

Each Comment has a `word_count property`. The Post object has an `average_comment_word_count` property which is an average of each of the Comment's `word_count`.

When I send a `DELETE` request on a particular comment, the app should recalculate the `average_comment_word_count` parameter. The way I thought it would work is like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
after_destroy :update_post_average_word_count

def update_post_average_word_count
  post_average_word_count = 0
  post.comments.each do |comment|
     post_average_word_count = post_average_word_count + comment.word_count
  end

  post_average_word_count / post.comments.count
  post.update_attributes average_word_count: post_average_word_count
end
```

However I get a database error because the app cannot find a reference to the post in question (because the comment is gone, cue Homer Simpson here)

Is there a different method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `before_destroy` and take this into account when calculating the post_average_word_count:

`post.update_attributes average_word_count: (post_average_word_count - self.word_count)`

Comment: If I use `before_destroy` wouldn't I need to exclude the comment being destroyed when computing the average?

Comment: Yes, you would. `post.update_attributes average_word_count: (post_average_word_count - self.word_count)`

Comment: And there's no way to preserve the "owner" of an object after it gets destroyed? I already have the methods written in `Comment` and would really like to avoid method duplication (or moving all the code into `Post`)

Comment: I'm also still getting an error that the `Post` object doesn't exist, when I try the latter approach